# How to create xml which has many namespace in it like the below

Tags: .net, xml, linq

Sample XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
   soapenv:Body>
      <recordClaim xmlns="http://webservices.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/lossnotification-v1_0">
         <requestHeader>
            <ns1:userId 
            <ns2:systemDateTime xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/zsoa">2010-04-21T17:52:53.156Z</ns2:systemDateTime>
            <ns3:systemName xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/zsoa">System</ns3:systemName>
            <ns4:messageReference xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/zsoa">P-1618 20100421T175253.448 GMT</ns4:messageReference>
            <ns5:functionName xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/zsoa">IB_CS_ClaimReg_ClaimInsert</ns5:functionName>
            <ns6:transactionStartDateTime xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/zsoa">2010-04-21T17:52:53.156Z</ns6:transactionStartDateTime>
         </requestHeader>
         <entityName>Claim</entityName>
         <newClaim>
            <ns7:claimSource xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim">FNOL</ns7:claimSource>
            <ns8:eventNumber xmlns:ns8="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim">2000059951</ns8:eventNumber>
            <ns9:policyExternalReference xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim"/>
            <ns10:policy xmlns:ns10="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim">
               <ns11:basicAutoInsurancePolicy xmlns:ns11="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                  <ns11:houseHoldNumber/>
                  <ns11:manualEntryIndicator>false</ns11:manualEntryIndicator>
                  <ns11:multicarPolicyIndicator>false</ns11:multicarPolicyIndicator>
                  <ns11:agentContact>
                     <ns12:agentCode xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">96</ns12:agentCode>
                     <ns13:agentDistrictCode xmlns:ns13="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">76</ns13:agentDistrictCode>
                     <ns14:agentName xmlns:ns14="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns14:firstName>Steve</ns14:firstName>
                        <ns14:lastName>Wilson</ns14:lastName>
                     </ns14:agentName>
                     <ns15:agentPhoneNumber xmlns:ns15="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns15:telephoneNumber>
                           <ns15:contactPointAsString>9158332201</ns15:contactPointAsString>
                        </ns15:telephoneNumber>
                     </ns15:agentPhoneNumber>
                     <ns16:agentRegionCode xmlns:ns16="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">35</ns16:agentRegionCode>
                  </ns11:agentContact>
                  <ns11:basicAutoInsurancePolicySummary>
                     <ns11:basicPolicy>
                        <ns11:alternativeReference/>
                        <ns11:policyDescription>Auto</ns11:policyDescription>
                        <ns11:policyNumber>0041919349</ns11:policyNumber>
                        <ns11:policyState>TX</ns11:policyState>
                        <ns11:policyStateCode>35</ns11:policyStateCode>
                        <ns11:policyStatus>SOK</ns11:policyStatus>
                        <ns11:policyType>Homeowners</ns11:policyType>
                        <ns11:umbrellaPolicyIndicator>false</ns11:umbrellaPolicyIndicator>
                     </ns11:basicPolicy>
                  </ns11:basicAutoInsurancePolicySummary>
                  <ns11:insured>
                     <ns17:basicPersonContactPoint xmlns:ns17="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns17:basicElectronicAddress>
                           <ns17:electronicAddress>
                              <ns17:electronicType>Proprietary</ns17:electronicType>
                           </ns17:electronicAddress>
                        </ns17:basicElectronicAddress>
                        <ns17:basicPerson>
                           <ns17:person>
                              <ns18:typeName xmlns:ns18="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Individual</ns18:typeName>
                           </ns17:person>
                           <ns17:personName>
                              <ns17:firstName>ROBERT</ns17:firstName>
                              <ns17:lastName>ARMSTRONG</ns17:lastName>
                           </ns17:personName>
                        </ns17:basicPerson>
                        <ns17:basicTelephoneNumber>
                           <ns17:isPrimaryTelephoneNumber>true</ns17:isPrimaryTelephoneNumber>
                           <ns17:telephoneNumber>
                              <ns19:typeName xmlns:ns19="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Home</ns19:typeName>
                              <ns17:contactPointAsString>2112122112</ns17:contactPointAsString>
                              <ns17:extension/>
                           </ns17:telephoneNumber>
                        </ns17:basicTelephoneNumber>
                     </ns17:basicPersonContactPoint>
                  </ns11:insured>
               </ns11:basicAutoInsurancePolicy>
            </ns10:policy>
            <ns20:policy xmlns:ns20="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim">
               <ns21:basicAutoInsurancePolicy xmlns:ns21="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                  <ns21:houseHoldNumber/>
                  <ns21:manualEntryIndicator>false</ns21:manualEntryIndicator>
                  <ns21:multicarPolicyIndicator>false</ns21:multicarPolicyIndicator>
                  <ns21:agentContact>
                     <ns22:agentCode xmlns:ns22="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">96</ns22:agentCode>
                     <ns23:agentDistrictCode xmlns:ns23="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">76</ns23:agentDistrictCode>
                     <ns24:agentName xmlns:ns24="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns24:firstName>Steve</ns24:firstName>
                        <ns24:lastName>Wilson</ns24:lastName>
                     </ns24:agentName>
                     <ns25:agentPhoneNumber xmlns:ns25="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns25:telephoneNumber>
                           <ns25:contactPointAsString>9158332201</ns25:contactPointAsString>
                        </ns25:telephoneNumber>
                     </ns25:agentPhoneNumber>
                     <ns26:agentRegionCode xmlns:ns26="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">35</ns26:agentRegionCode>
                  </ns21:agentContact>
                  <ns21:basicAutoInsurancePolicySummary>
                     <ns21:basicPolicy>
                        <ns21:alternativeReference/>
                        <ns21:policyDescription>Auto</ns21:policyDescription>
                        <ns21:policyNumber>0041919349</ns21:policyNumber>
                        <ns21:policyState>TX</ns21:policyState>
                        <ns21:policyStateCode>35</ns21:policyStateCode>
                        <ns21:policyStatus>SOK</ns21:policyStatus>
                        <ns21:policyType>Homeowners</ns21:policyType>
                        <ns21:umbrellaPolicyIndicator>false</ns21:umbrellaPolicyIndicator>
                     </ns21:basicPolicy>
                  </ns21:basicAutoInsurancePolicySummary>
                  <ns21:insured>
                     <ns27:basicPersonContactPoint xmlns:ns27="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns27:basicElectronicAddress>
                           <ns27:electronicAddress>
                              <ns27:electronicType>Proprietary</ns27:electronicType>
                           </ns27:electronicAddress>
                        </ns27:basicElectronicAddress>
                        <ns27:basicPerson>
                           <ns27:person>
                              <ns28:typeName xmlns:ns28="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Individual</ns28:typeName>
                           </ns27:person>
                           <ns27:personName>
                              <ns27:firstName>ROBERT</ns27:firstName>
                              <ns27:lastName>ARMSTRONG</ns27:lastName>
                           </ns27:personName>
                        </ns27:basicPerson>
                        <ns27:basicTelephoneNumber>
                           <ns27:isPrimaryTelephoneNumber>true</ns27:isPrimaryTelephoneNumber>
                           <ns27:telephoneNumber>
                              <ns29:typeName xmlns:ns29="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Home</ns29:typeName>
                              <ns27:contactPointAsString>2112122112</ns27:contactPointAsString>
                              <ns27:extension/>
                           </ns27:telephoneNumber>
                        </ns27:basicTelephoneNumber>
                     </ns27:basicPersonContactPoint>
                  </ns21:insured>
               </ns21:basicAutoInsurancePolicy>
            </ns20:policy>
            <ns30:policy xmlns:ns30="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim">
               <ns31:basicAutoInsurancePolicy xmlns:ns31="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                  <ns31:houseHoldNumber/>
                  <ns31:manualEntryIndicator>false</ns31:manualEntryIndicator>
                  <ns31:multicarPolicyIndicator>false</ns31:multicarPolicyIndicator>
                  <ns31:agentContact>
                     <ns32:agentCode xmlns:ns32="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">96</ns32:agentCode>
                     <ns33:agentDistrictCode xmlns:ns33="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">76</ns33:agentDistrictCode>
                     <ns34:agentName xmlns:ns34="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns34:firstName>Steve</ns34:firstName>
                        <ns34:lastName>Wilson</ns34:lastName>
                     </ns34:agentName>
                     <ns35:agentPhoneNumber xmlns:ns35="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns35:telephoneNumber>
                           <ns35:contactPointAsString>9158332201</ns35:contactPointAsString>
                        </ns35:telephoneNumber>
                     </ns35:agentPhoneNumber>
                     <ns36:agentRegionCode xmlns:ns36="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">35</ns36:agentRegionCode>
                  </ns31:agentContact>
                  <ns31:basicAutoInsurancePolicySummary>
                     <ns31:basicPolicy>
                        <ns31:alternativeReference>HX011081</ns31:alternativeReference>
                        <ns31:policyDescription>BASIC FORM (TEXAS)</ns31:policyDescription>
                        <ns31:policyNumber>0929624151</ns31:policyNumber>
                        <ns31:policyState>TX</ns31:policyState>
                        <ns31:policyStateCode>35</ns31:policyStateCode>
                        <ns31:policyStatus>SOK</ns31:policyStatus>
                        <ns31:policyType>Homeowners</ns31:policyType>
                        <ns31:umbrellaPolicyIndicator>false</ns31:umbrellaPolicyIndicator>
                     </ns31:basicPolicy>
                  </ns31:basicAutoInsurancePolicySummary>
                  <ns31:insured>
                     <ns37:basicPersonContactPoint xmlns:ns37="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns37:basicElectronicAddress>
                           <ns37:electronicAddress>
                              <ns37:electronicType>Proprietary</ns37:electronicType>
                           </ns37:electronicAddress>
                        </ns37:basicElectronicAddress>
                        <ns37:basicPerson>
                           <ns37:person>
                              <ns38:typeName xmlns:ns38="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Individual</ns38:typeName>
                           </ns37:person>
                           <ns37:personName>
                              <ns37:firstName>ROBERT</ns37:firstName>
                              <ns37:lastName>ARMSTRONG</ns37:lastName>
                           </ns37:personName>
                        </ns37:basicPerson>
                        <ns37:basicTelephoneNumber>
                           <ns37:isPrimaryTelephoneNumber>true</ns37:isPrimaryTelephoneNumber>
                           <ns37:telephoneNumber>
                              <ns39:typeName xmlns:ns39="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Home</ns39:typeName>
                              <ns37:contactPointAsString>2112122112</ns37:contactPointAsString>
                              <ns37:extension/>
                           </ns37:telephoneNumber>
                        </ns37:basicTelephoneNumber>
                     </ns37:basicPersonContactPoint>
                  </ns31:insured>
               </ns31:basicAutoInsurancePolicy>
            </ns30:policy>
            <ns40:claim xmlns:ns40="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim">
               <ns40:claimAlternateReference>P-1618</ns40:claimAlternateReference>
               <ns40:claimExternalReference/>
               <ns40:dateOfDiscovery>2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</ns40:dateOfDiscovery>
               <ns40:manualEntryIndicator>false</ns40:manualEntryIndicator>
               <ns40:rekeyedClaimExternalReference>HX011081</ns40:rekeyedClaimExternalReference>
               <ns40:timeZone>Central Time</ns40:timeZone>
               <ns40:isDualClaim>false</ns40:isDualClaim>
               <ns40:isInformationOnly>false</ns40:isInformationOnly>
               <ns40:isPremise>true</ns40:isPremise>
               <ns40:isAutoSubmit>true</ns40:isAutoSubmit>
               <ns40:claimFolder>
                  <ns40:policyNumber>0929624151</ns40:policyNumber>
               </ns40:claimFolder>
            </ns40:claim>
            <ns41:fullLossEvent xmlns:ns41="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim">
               <ns41:lossDateTime>2010-01-01T09:00:00.000Z</ns41:lossDateTime>
               <ns41:lossDescriptionValue/>
               <ns41:lossLocation/>
               <ns41:lossReportedBy>ROBERT ARMSTRONG</ns41:lossReportedBy>
               <ns41:lossReportedDateTime>2010-04-21T17:48:06.466Z</ns41:lossReportedDateTime>
               <ns41:lossSummary>Freeze-Slab/Foundation Damage</ns41:lossSummary>
               <ns41:lossTypeCode>Property</ns41:lossTypeCode>
               <ns41:reportedByAILR>ROBERT ARMSTRONG</ns41:reportedByAILR>
               <ns41:locationAddress>
                  <ns42:addressLines xmlns:ns42="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party"/>
                  <ns43:isPrimaryAddress xmlns:ns43="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">true</ns43:isPrimaryAddress>
                  <ns44:postalAddress xmlns:ns44="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                     <ns44:city/>
                     <ns44:country>USA</ns44:country>
                     <ns44:postalCode/>
                     <ns44:region>CA</ns44:region>
                  </ns44:postalAddress>
               </ns41:locationAddress>
               <ns41:lossEvent>
                  <ns45:typeName xmlns:ns45="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">In home</ns45:typeName>
                  <ns46:description xmlns:ns46="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/activityconditionplace">sdfdsfdsfdsf</ns46:description>
                  <ns47:externalReference xmlns:ns47="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/activityconditionplace"/>
               </ns41:lossEvent>
            </ns41:fullLossEvent>
            <ns48:contactInfo xmlns:ns48="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/claim">
               <ns48:alternativeReference>Individual</ns48:alternativeReference>
               <ns48:citationNumber/>
               <ns48:comments/>
               <ns48:insuranceCarrierClaimNumber/>
               <ns48:insuranceCarrierPolicyNumber/>
               <ns48:insuredBy/>
               <ns48:isInterpreterNeededIndicator>false</ns48:isInterpreterNeededIndicator>
               <ns48:language>English</ns48:language>
               <ns48:relationshipToInsured>Self</ns48:relationshipToInsured>
               <ns48:isInjured>false</ns48:isInjured>
               <ns48:isOtherCarrier>false</ns48:isOtherCarrier>
               <ns48:isPedestrianIndicator>false</ns48:isPedestrianIndicator>
               <ns48:fullpartyrolepersonview>
                  <ns49:personRole xmlns:ns49="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">Insured</ns49:personRole>
                  <ns50:basicPersonContactPoint xmlns:ns50="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                     <ns50:basicElectronicAddress>
                        <ns50:emailPreferredIndicator>false</ns50:emailPreferredIndicator>
                        <ns50:electronicAddress>
                           <ns50:contactPointAsString/>
                           <ns50:electronicType>Proprietary</ns50:electronicType>
                        </ns50:electronicAddress>
                     </ns50:basicElectronicAddress>
                     <ns50:basicPerson>
                        <ns50:personName>
                           <ns50:firstName>ROBERT</ns50:firstName>
                           <ns50:lastName>ARMSTRONG</ns50:lastName>
                           <ns50:middleName/>
                        </ns50:personName>
                     </ns50:basicPerson>
                     <ns50:basicPostalAddress>
                        <ns50:addressLines>6808 CAN CUN LN</ns50:addressLines>
                        <ns50:careOfAddressee/>
                        <ns50:isPrimaryAddress>false</ns50:isPrimaryAddress>
                        <ns50:postalAddress>
                           <ns51:typeName xmlns:ns51="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Mailing</ns51:typeName>
                           <ns50:statusAsString>Verified</ns50:statusAsString>
                           <ns50:city>EL PASO</ns50:city>
                           <ns50:country>USA</ns50:country>
                           <ns50:houseNumber/>
                           <ns50:postalCode>79912</ns50:postalCode>
                           <ns50:postalCodeExtension>2327</ns50:postalCodeExtension>
                           <ns50:region>TX</ns50:region>
                           <ns50:street>6808</ns50:street>
                        </ns50:postalAddress>
                     </ns50:basicPostalAddress>
                     <ns50:basicTelephoneNumber>
                        <ns50:isPrimaryTelephoneNumber>true</ns50:isPrimaryTelephoneNumber>
                        <ns50:telephoneNumber>
                           <ns50:contactPointAsString>2112122112</ns50:contactPointAsString>
                        </ns50:telephoneNumber>
                     </ns50:basicTelephoneNumber>
                     <ns50:basicTelephoneNumber>
                        <ns50:telephoneNumber>
                           <ns52:typeName xmlns:ns52="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Home</ns52:typeName>
                           <ns50:contactPointAsString>2112122112</ns50:contactPointAsString>
                        </ns50:telephoneNumber>
                     </ns50:basicTelephoneNumber>
                  </ns50:basicPersonContactPoint>
               </ns48:fullpartyrolepersonview>
               <ns48:property>
                  <ns53:description xmlns:ns53="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">sdfsdfsdf</ns53:description>
                  <ns54:propertyType xmlns:ns54="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">Building</ns54:propertyType>
                  <ns55:propertyDamages xmlns:ns55="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                     <ns55:alternativeReference>Building</ns55:alternativeReference>
                     <ns55:description>Attic</ns55:description>
                  </ns55:propertyDamages>
                  <ns56:propertyDamages xmlns:ns56="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                     <ns56:alternativeReference>Building</ns56:alternativeReference>
                     <ns56:description>Bathroom 1</ns56:description>
                  </ns56:propertyDamages>
                  <ns57:propertyDamages xmlns:ns57="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                     <ns57:alternativeReference>Building</ns57:alternativeReference>
                     <ns57:description>Bathroom 2</ns57:description>
                  </ns57:propertyDamages>
                  <ns58:propertyDamages xmlns:ns58="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                     <ns58:alternativeReference>Building</ns58:alternativeReference>
                     <ns58:description>Bathroom 3</ns58:description>
                  </ns58:propertyDamages>
               </ns48:property>
               <ns48:property>
                  <ns59:description xmlns:ns59="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement"/>
                  <ns60:propertyType xmlns:ns60="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">Contents</ns60:propertyType>
                  <ns61:locationAddress xmlns:ns61="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                     <ns62:postalAddress xmlns:ns62="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/party">
                        <ns62:city/>
                        <ns62:country>USA</ns62:country>
                        <ns62:houseNumber/>
                        <ns62:postalCode/>
                        <ns62:region/>
                        <ns62:street/>
                     </ns62:postalAddress>
                  </ns61:locationAddress>
                  <ns63:propertyDamages xmlns:ns63="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement">
                     <ns63:alternativeReference>Contents</ns63:alternativeReference>
                     <ns63:description>Business Personal Property</ns63:description>
                  </ns63:propertyDamages>
               </ns48:property>
            </ns48:contactInfo>
         </newClaim>
      </recordClaim>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: this is a XML which has many Namespace

Comment: What exactly is your problem? And why do you need to produce such absurd XML?

Comment: i need to create this huge xml  <ns18:typeName xmlns:ns18="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/common">Individual</ns18:typeName> this kind of namespace how to create ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not going to try to reproduce your huge example (which isn't even valid, as namespace aliases such as `ns1` aren't declared in what you've shown), but as a shorter sample:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XNamespace foo = "http://foo.com/foo";
        XNamespace bar = "http://bar.com/baz";
        XNamespace baz = "http://baz.com/baz";

        XElement root = new XElement("root",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "foo", foo.ToString()),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "baz", bar.ToString()),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "bar", baz.ToString()),
            new XElement(foo + "a",
                "Some text",
                new XElement(bar + "b",
                    new XElement(baz + "c", "Deep element text"))));

        Console.WriteLine(root);
    }
}
```

Result (indented by hand):

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://foo.com/foo"
      xmlns:baz="http://bar.com/baz"
      xmlns:bar="http://baz.com/baz">
  <foo:a>Some text
    <baz:b>
      <bar:c>Deep element text</bar:c>
    </baz:b>
  </foo:a>
</root>
```

Comment: <ns1:userId xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/claimmanagement/2009/01/zsoa">uswshr50</ns1:userId> 
ns1: we have definition like i have mentioned above

Comment: @user980408: Okay - but look at what you actually posted. It ended mid-element. Again, I don't think you've posted a very clear example. Now, what in my solution doesn't work for you?